# How to get the Body of an email in a selection of emails?

Tags: vba, outlook

The command to get the Body of the email is not pulling the body from the email, in a selection of emails, being processed in a loop.

How do I set the itm for the `sText = itm.Body` command?

```
Dim itm         As Outlook.MailItem
Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
Dim Selection   As Selection
Dim strFileName As String, strExt As String
Dim objAtt      As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder  As String
Dim email_date  As Date
Dim date_ext    As String
Dim sText       As String
Dim Intext_date As String
Dim Mail_date   As Date
Dim email_date_temp As String

saveFolder = "C:\elan\Various\email_attachments\"

Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection

For Each itm In Selection
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        
        strFileName = objAtt.DisplayName
        
        ' get the last 5 characters or last 4 for .xls for the file extension
        strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 5)
        
        If Mid(strExt, 1, 1) <> "." Then
            strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 4)
        End If
        
        If strExt = ".xls" Or strExt = ".xlsx" Then
            ' clean the File Name
            ReplaceCharsForFileName strFileName, "-"
            
            ' Get Body of email
            Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
            sText = itm.Body
            Debug.Print sText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to set the `itm` object in the code in the following way:

```
Set itm = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
```

In your code the `itm` object is already assigned with each loop iteration:

```
For Each itm In Selection
```

So, the code could look like that:

```
For Each itm In Selection
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        
        strFileName = objAtt.DisplayName
        
        ' get the last 5 characters or last 4 for .xls for the file extension
        strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 5)
        
        If Mid(strExt, 1, 1) <> "." Then
            strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 4)
            
        End If
        If strExt = ".xls" Or strExt = ".xlsx" Then
            ' clean the File Name
            ReplaceCharsForFileName strFileName, "-"
            
            ' Get Body of email           
            
            sText = itm.Body
            Debug.Print sText
```

Remember that you get the message body in the inner loop which means if you have multiple attached files you will get the same message body for each of them.